# Dragging object in corona

Tags: coronasdk

I have an object that I just wanted to move up and down. How could I make that object still move up and down without actually touching the object? Here is my codes so far:

```
function Scientist:touch( event )
if event.phase == "began" then

        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(  nil)
         self.markY = self.y    
         self.isFocus = false
elseif event.phase == "moved" then

        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY
        self.y = y

elseif event.phase == "ended"  or event.phase == "cancelled" then

        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)

end

        return true

end
        Scientist:addEventListener('touch', Scientist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a large rectangle, set the alpha to 0, and make the width `display.contentWidth` and the height `display.contentHeight`.  When you touch that rectangle, have that move the Scientist in a similar way you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Make a rectangle on entire page with alpha set to 0.01:

```
local background = display.newRect(display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight)
```

then write a touch listener like you did `background:addEventListener('touch', background)`

here is the complete code for you:

```
function Scientist:touch( event )
  if event.phase == "began" then
         display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(  nil)
         Scientist.markY = Scientist.y    
         self.isFocus = false
  elseif event.phase == "moved" then    
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + Scientist.markY
        Scientist.y = y    
  elseif event.phase == "ended"  or event.phase == "cancelled" then    
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)    
  end    
return true
end
Scientist:addEventListener('touch', Scientist)
```